# PHP+PDO - prepared statement info

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Even after a lot of reading, I didn't get one thing.
Is PDO escaping data IF I am NOT using bindValue or bindParam ?
Maybe I didn't understand what "prepare" exactly does. I know it's storing a procedure as an object. I know it's performance benefits (even used it with transactions) but escaping is the only thing I didn't understand

Suppose this:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db']['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db']['dbname'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password'], $config['db']['options']);

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (:col1, :col2)");

$result = $query->execute(array('col1' => $val_col1, 'col2' => $val_col2));
```

Where/when is the actual escape being done ? While **preparing** or while **binding** a param/value ?
What if I'm skipping this:

```
$query->bindParam(":col1", $val_col1);
$query->bindParam(":col2", $val_col2);
```

Note that I have **PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES** set to **false** (it's set in $config array)

Using PHP 5.4.13 and MySQL 5.1.67

Answer (score 1):

Passing an array into `execute()` is just a syntax sugar for the series of bindValues performed then internally. So,

> Is PDO escaping data IF I am NOT using bindValue or bindParam ?

Yes, as long as you have your data substituted with placeholders.

> I know it's performance benefits

There are **no** performance benefits

> Where/when is the actual escape being done?  While preparing...

- It cannot be done while preparing, if you think it over a bit. There is no data to "escape" yet.
- "Escaping" is not that you think it is. "Formatting" is a more correct term. PDO does format every value from the passed array as a string.
- Formatting is done before execution when emulation mode is on and [never when off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/285587)

Comment: When I thought about performance benefits I was thinking about multiple queries (let's say inserts) with different values.

Do you mean placeholders as "?" or ":colname" works too ?

I thought disabling emulation forces escaping everytime

Comment: Thanks :) Seems I was thinking backwards :)